# What If I posted a question and on the way I myself resolved the problem. Sometimes, intermediate help by SO and sometimes solely by me

Tags: discussion

In this case,

1. Is it OK to post your answer to the (your own) queston ? What happens if I myself accept it as an useful answer ?
   Does that lead to mis-behaving in SO or Is it fine to move ahead without much worries ?
2. Sometimes, on the way to finding an answer with self-coding or someone in SO's intermediate help..let us say, I could resolve the problem I quoted in SO. In this scenario, Is it OK to post your answer such that it can help other newbies to refer my code later ? Does that make sense or NOT ? Here the intention is to complete the loop of the Question and enable your code to be visible for others who may visit your question during their coding days...

In both the above scenarios, intention is NOT to get bonus points but ensure the question loop is closed and help other fellow newbies when they find themselves in touble in similar contexts...

Thanks.

Comment: nice reputation :P

Comment: You can definitely self-answer, but please don't do that for problems that turn out to be caused by a trivial error or overly specific to your situation. And of course make sure the question and answer adhere to the SO rules and guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it OK to post your answer to the (your own) queston ?

[Yes, it is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can even post the answer at the same time as the question (there is a checkbox in the ask question page that opens up another editor for the answer). We wouldn't do that if that was not OK.

> What happens if I myself accept it as an useful answer ?

Nothing much would happen. You will not get any reputation, if that's what you are asking.

> Does that lead to mis-behaving in SO or Is it fine to move ahead without much worries ?

No, it is fine.

---

I can't parse your second point. But - if the answer is useful and is a high quality answer (as per our standards), go ahead, post it. Link to any material that helped you along the way.

If this was by some help by another person, you can invite them to post the answer. If they don't, within a reasonable amount of time, go ahead and post (you can mention them and that they helped you out).

Comment: @mehow - well, in general, questions and answers are expected to adhere to a minimum quality standard. We don't make exceptions for self-answered posts.